# how to use threading.Semaphore with ThreadPoolExecutor in python

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I want to know how I can use something like `Semaphore` in `ThreadPoolExecutor`
My code is like this

```
def download_one(url):
    requests.get(url)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return 'ok'

def download_all(urls):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=7) as executor:
        return executor.map(download_one, urls, timeout=20)

download_all(["url-1", "url-2"])
```

My code works very well this way
But the problem I have is that I may call the `download_all` function several times with different `urls`
An update comes to my program and those updates are the `urls` and I want to transfer them to the `download_all` function.

However, I want it to work when I first call the `download_all` function
And when I call it a second time, wait until it's done and then start again

So that there are always `7 workers` running and not added to the `workers` when the function is added several times.

> `with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=7) as executor:`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, simply make sure that you are using only a single executor for all of your calls.  Something like the following should work:

```
def download_one(url):
    requests.get(url)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return 'ok'

def download_all(executor, urls):
    return executor.map(download_one, urls, timeout=20)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=7) as executor:
    ...
    download_all(executor, ["url-1", "url-2"])
    ...
    download_all(executor, ["url-3", "url-4", "url-5"])
    ...
    download_all(executor, ["url-6"])
```